# call asp.net webmethod in windows project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

How do I call this `WebMethod` in ASP.NET from a Windows application?

I have tried using web request post method, but it is returning the XML of the ASP.NET page.

Here is my web method:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string Senddata(string value)
{
    return "datareceived" + value;
}
```

Comment: Right click on project in solution explorer, Add service reference , specify the URL of your web service. That will create a proxy class in your project, use that to call your method.

Comment: habib it is a  method in the asp.net project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var theWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://YOURURL/YOURPAGE.aspx/Senddata");
theWebRequest.Method = "POST";
theWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
theWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");

using (var writer = theWebRequest.GetRequestStream()) 
{
    string send = null;
    send = "{\"value\":\"test\"}";

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send);

    writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var theWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theWebRequest.GetResponse();
var theResponseStream = new StreamReader(theWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

string result = theResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

// Do something with the result
TextBox1.Text = result;
```

Note: You need to replace `YOURURL` and `YOURPAGE` with real values.

Comment: thanks a lot it really worked.. but what if we do not know the parameter is "value"?

Comment: As far as I know, the name of the parameter must match, what scenario would you not know the parameter name?

Comment: no i dont know that is the problem i even dont know the method name. i was jus given the "somewebsite.com/somthing.aspx"