# How to access existing WebMethod from ApiController

Tags: asp.net, api, webmethod, asp.net-apicontroller

I am building services on top of an existing application in .NET. There are `WebMethods` in the existing solution which are part of `aspx.cs` Say e.g GetDetails.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public static StudentDetails[] GetNext(string id)
{         
      BAL obj = new BAL();
      List<Details> details = new List<Details>();
      DataSet ds = obj.Display(id);
      ...
}
```

I have a added an API Controller to build the services, i want to call `GetNext` method from the controller. Is this possible?

I tried adding web reference but i am unable to find the method when i try to create the web reference and all i could find on the internet was how to call the `WebMethod` using js/jquery.

I would like to know how to call the method from C#

Comment: Try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597563/2932057)

Comment: Are they in the same project? Is the ApiController able to directly call the class that has the web method?

Comment: @Nkosi yes in the same solution.

Comment: @Ishan then just call the static `GetNext` from the ApiController. done.